# Fullcalendar scoping fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I have a web-application with ruby on rails back-end and javascript / jquery fullcalendar.

On the weekView / monthView I would like to scope events (that are coming from a backend) and display them in the following manner:

[image]

How would you put display only two (one is also OK) with button `more` and pluck all others events details for the particular day? I have a look at `eventRender` and `afterEventRender` methods. However it seems they get only one event event.

PS. Data is prepared by `ruby on rails` function:

```
group_by(&:service_start_date_time).each do |service_start_date_time, events|
  events.first.visible = true
  events.first.save
  return events
end
```